# Lottie has 70 issues Xcode 12.5.1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Trying to import Lottie into a project on Xcode 12.5.1. I've followed the Github instructions -- set the branch to `lottie/macos-spm`, disabled Dead Code Stripping in the App Target.. but when I build it shows errors all over. What's going on?

My target iOS build is 14.3

[image]

Comment: I don't think you were supposed to change the branch to `lottie/macos-spm`. That's if you want to use Lottie in a macOS app.

Comment: Ahh, that could explain it. Thanks!